# CMake march hardware

Tags: c++, c, cmake

What is the CMake way to enable the equivalent of GCC's `-march=`, particularly `-march=native`? Is there really nothing better than `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG`, such as:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-march=native" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_MARCH_NATIVE)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_MARCH_NATIVE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native")
endif()
```

Comment: It is exactly CMake way, I'd say.

Comment: Agreed. A lot of the nice convenient macros you use in CMake look like this when you dig into them.

Comment: @arrowd: But this should only be done for some build types, e.g. release rather than debug. Shouldn't it? Also - what about MSVC?

Comment: Personally, my main issue with the code in my question is that it is build-time decision made by the author, not the user. All such decisions ought to be made by users. Sure, at the end of the day I do know what compiler I'm using so I can also add `-march` correctly, but seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this feature test is an appropriate way to apply the argument to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Perhaps an improvement might be to hide this behind an `option`, as @LeviMorrison suggests.

```
option(OPTIMIZE_FOR_NATIVE "Build with -march=native" OFF)
```

Comment: @OP: note that CMake isn't the actual compiler, so it's sensible for it to manage compilation options as sets of compiler flags.  It would be idiomatic to offer preset build types (RELEASE, DEBUG, etc) that add certain default flags.